# PHP NOW() Error

Tags: php, mysql

I need a little help with this, I am trying to insert some data into a MYSQL table which includes the now values for date & time for orders.

Code:

```
$query= "INSERT INTO ordertable
VALUES ('".$listauthor."','".$ordernumber.",'"NOW()"','"NOW()"')";
```

Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\createbasket.php on line 15
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to encapsulate `NOW()` with quotes. You'd need to do:

```
$query= "INSERT INTO ordertable 
             VALUES ('".$listauthor."','".$ordernumber."',NOW(),NOW())";
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. However when I try this solution I receive this error:
"MYSQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0,NOW(),NOW())' at line 2."

Answer (score 5):

Remove the quotes from around `NOW()` ... it's a MySQL function ... not a string.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query= "INSERT INTO ordertable VALUES ('".$listauthor."','".$ordernumber.",'"NOW()"','"NOW()"')";
```

Shouldn't be quotes around NOW

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ordertable VALUES ('".$listauthur."','".$ordernumber."', NOW(), NOW())";
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, however when using the above solution the following error occurs:
"MYSQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0,NOW(),NOW())' at line 2"

Answer (score 1):

Now() is a mysql function so don't need to put it inside single/double quotes.When you put inside quotes then it will treat it as variable.Just write as follows : 
$query= "INSERT INTO ordertable VALUES ('".$listauthor."','".$ordernumber.",NOW(),NOW())";